# Validar Expresión regular decimales

Tags: java, regex

Estoy intentando realizar una expresión regular en donde tenga dos decimales pero que estos no sean `.00` pero si `.10` o `.01`.

Tengo esta expresión regular pero no puedo definir el rango que solo sean dos decimales, ya que si pongo ejemplo `.213` me lo marca como válido:

```
^[0-9]{1,18}\.0?[1-9]\d*{1,2}$
```

Comment: tienen que ser especificamente .10 o .01? o cualquier decimal que no sea .00?

Answer (score 0):

Este patrón coincide con un número con 2 decimales

```
^\d+\.\d{2}$
```

Una opción sería agregar una inspección negativa que nos asegure que *no está seguido por dos ceros*

```
^\d+\.(?!00)\d{2}$
```

Pero hay una mejor opción, más eficiente.

Para que los decimales no permitan `00` se pueden ofrecer las diferentes opciones, caracter por caracter. Desenrollando el problema, sería:

- un `0` seguido de un dígito que no es un cero `0[1-9]`, o
- un dígito que no es un cero, seguido de cualquier dígito `[1-9]\d`
- ambas opciones dentro de un grupo `(?:opción a|opción b)`

La expresión final queda:

```
^\d+\.(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)$
```